# How do I make Spring Zuul High Available?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I would like to use Zuul as a Proxy for some REST services that I'm using. My question is: since I'm running it as a Spring Boot Application, is there any way to configure it for High Availability?

EDIT: do I need to deploy my application inside an application server which supports HA?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can deploy multiple instances of your Zuul Proxy behind a load balancer to achieve High Availability.

For example in AWS, you would put it behind an [ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) (Elastic Load Balancer).

You can continue to use the standard Spring Boot Executable JAR format without issue.